# Cronjobs not working sometimes

Tags: magento-1.8, cron

I am working on Magento cron jobs issue. We have 50+ cron jobs in system which are scheduled and runs 24/7. But, there are some cron jobs like aoescheduler_heartbeat, aoecachecleaner, aoequotecleaner and captcha_delete_expired_images not running sometimes(ie with in 24hrs, 3 or 4 times not working). Is this due to configuration problem or memory problem or some other problem. If anyone of You know the solution, please post. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have access to the Cron log on the server?

Comment: Yes, I have access to Cron log on the server

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if you have one particular cron task that takes a long time to execute. For instance if you have the following settings:

- "Missed if Not Run Within" = 15
- "Schedule ahead for" = 15

Then if cron_task_1 takes 16 minutes to execute, any other tasks blocked by cron_task_1 will be marked as "missed" and a schedule may not be generated for 30 minutes instead of 15.

You need to assess your cron tasks and find the ones that are taking a long time. Check the `cron_schedule` database table and look for big gaps between the `executed_at` and `finished_at` times. You may need to change your settings to allow for longer cron tasks or remove these from the Magento cron and run them separately using a tool like [n98-magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun).

I'd also recommend installing [AOE Scheduler](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler) to give better visibility over your cron tasks and also give you the ability to run multiple simultaneous crons.

Answer (score 1):

Try this link. You should prioritize the cron jobs according to your requirements.
http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/magento-cron-scheduler.html

Comment: Thanks Ajay, for quick solution. I had prioritize them, but only sometimes they are not running ie also at night time.